# Dhikr isn't giving me dramatic improvement in all spheres of life. Why not?

Tags: practical-islam, dhikr

I have tried many kind of dhikrs with the exception of reading Quran in Arabic because I don't know the language. I have said thousands of times estagfirullah, la ilahe ilallah etc. Sometimes I feel like this dhikr not only does not improve my situation but makes it worse. Even the properties of heart after dhikr I feel as if they have become dramatically worse. I feel that love, respect and other good feelings towards Allah have dramatically decreased. And I fear even the appearance of bad feelings towards Allah.

To my understanding, dhikr is supposed to give me dramatic improvements in all spheres in life, but that doesn't seem to be happening. Why isn't this working?

Comment: Dhikr isn't the same as du'a. What sort of results are you expecting dhikr to provide, and why are you expecting them?

Comment: Dramatic improvement in all sferes of life.

Comment: That information should be included in the question itself so the community can understand what you need and are expecting in an answer; leaving it in comments or just expecting people to guess important details leads to an unanswerable question. Consider the edits I made to better understand how we expect questions to be asked here.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific question, I think it unlikely that you will find an answer from strangers on the internet because it is very personal to you. However you might consider learning to read the Quran in Arabic language. If you are reading a translation then you are not reading the Quran per se, but a translation of the Quran. I would suggest that if you know some worthy person you should consult him.

Also bear in mind that changes in your life are not contingent on what you do but on what Allah (SWT) wills.

Answer (score 1):

First a general point: *dhiker* goes with other requirements for success, such as a healthy body and mind that in turn correlate with many other things such as sound life choices, avoidance of sins, having good relations, and a spiritual connection. *Dhikr* can't be a substitute for these other important things in life and religion. It is certainly not one definite path to "dramatic improvement in all spheres of life!"

Here is a relevant saying from [Imam Ali ibn Musa, ar-Ridha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali_al-Ridha), a pious scholar from the bloodline of the Holy Prophet (pbuh) on the importance of a balanced life for a sound religious experience:

> اجْتَهِدُوا أَنْ يَكُونَ زَمَانُكُمْ أَرْبَعَ سَاعَاتٍ سَاعَةً مِنْهُ لِمُنَاجَاتِهِ وَ سَاعَةً لِأَمْرِ الْمَعَاشِ وَ سَاعَةً لِمُعَاشَرَةِ الْإِخْوَانِ الثِّقَاتِ وَ الَّذِينَ يُعَرِّفُونَكُمْ عُيُوبَكُمْ وَ يَخْلُصُونَ لَكُمْ فِي الْبَاطِنِ وَ سَاعَةً تَخْلُونَ فِيهَا لِلَذَّاتِكُمْ وَ بِهَذِهِ السَّاعَةِ تَقْدِرُونَ عَلَى الثَّلَاثِ السَّاعَاتِ لَا تُحَدِّثُوا أَنْفُسَكُمْ بِالْفَقْرِ وَ لَا بِطُولِ الْعُمُرِ فَإِنَّهُ مَنْ حَدَّثَ نَفْسَهُ بِالْفَقْرِ بَخِلَ وَ مَنْ حَدَّثَهَا بِطُولِ الْعُمُرِ حَرَصَ اجْعَلُوا لِأَنْفُسِكُمْ حَظّاً مِنَ الدُّنْيَا بِإِعْطَائِهَا مَا تَشْتَهِي مِنَ الْحَلَالِ وَ مَا لَمْ يَثلِمُ الْمُرُوءَةَ وَ لَا سَرَفَ فِيهِ وَ اسْتَعِينُوا بِذَلِكَ عَلَى أُمُورِ الدِّينِ فَإِنَّهُ نَرْوِي لَيْسَ مِنَّا مَنْ تَرَكَ دُنْيَاهُ لِدِينِهِ وَ دِينَهُ لِدُنْيَاه‏
>
> Struggle to divide your time in four: a time for prayer, a time for earning livelihood, a time for meeting trustworthy brethren and those who inform you about your faults but love you sincerely in their hearts, and a time spared for your pleasures (or leisure). And by this last time you will be successful in the other three times... Allow your self an enjoyment of the world from what you desire from the lawful enjoyments and that which doesn't violate perfection and doesn't exceed. And use these enjoyments to aid yourself in fulfilling matters of religion as it has been narrated (from the Messenger of Allah pbuh) that he who abandons the world for religion or abandons religion for the world is not from us.
> ([source](http://lib.eshia.ir/27146/1/337))

In my experience too many people who become fretful with their spiritual life must check their lives for imbalance in the four occupations explained in the above narration.

An imbalanced lifestyle can led to an imbalanced mental state, impairing our ability to a maintain a fruitful spiritual life. Mental health is generally key not just to worldly success but spiritual progress for mind is the ruler of our existence.

Moreover, in the tradition of Irfan and spirituality, not all forms of *dhikr* are recommendable to the lay person. Shia spiritual scholars particularly discourage lengthy utterances of *tahlil* for it is the most overwhelming Islamic doctrine and its full significance can't be born by the average person. They say this dhikr invokes the highest level of Divine Awe and Majesty which can be psychologically overwhelming to the uninitiated. They in fact cite individual clerics who permanently impaired their spiritual progress by excessive concentration on the wrong *dhikr* causing a negative feedback in their soul towards spirituality in general!

For they laymen, they instead recommend *dhikr*s that have gentler meanings such as *Alhamd u li Allah*, *Ya Rahman o Ya Raheem*, *Ya Latif*, or salutations upon the Prophet (pbuh). And they may discourage long dhikr at all and rather advise the person to suffice to the obligatory *ibadat* such as the five time daily *salat*.

At any rate, these religious mantra more than doing any miracle, will help engender a better attitude to God and spirituality in one's heart, and that must be the primary goal.

Note that in the above discussion, by *dhikr*, repeated recital of specific phrases was meant, not general remembrance of Allah that is a recommended state for all believers.